# Angular material drag and drop over item, not between

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-material-7

I would like to add members to groups by dragging them over the specified group, however, the default behavior of angular material drag and drop is that it's placing items between other elements. Currently, I have a list of groups and the second list of members. The expected behavior is that I would be able to drag members and drop them to the groups, however, by default I can drop them only between groups (as shown on screen). Is there any possibility to drop items over other items, so they "jump" on that item and not around?

[image]

Comment: I know this is old, but were you able to resolve it?  I'm trying to do somewhat similar thing in mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709758/angular-material-drag-and-drop-merge-elements

Comment: @Khobar I wasn't able to solve it, can't help, sorry